# How to find which version of FacebookSDK.framework for iOS you are using?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am maintaining an older iOS project and I can't seem to find which version of the `FacebookSDK.framework` the project is using.

Any ideas where I can find that?

**[Update]**

All I have is `FacebookSDK.framework` in the project directory.
Is the version included anywhere in those headers? looked everywhere without much luck.
thanks

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736831/find-facebook-sdk-version

Comment: Thanks Sawsan for pointing in the right direction. To close this off, [click here for the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736831/find-facebook-sdk-version)