# Find Facebook SDK Version on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I know I'm using the latest version (v3.2.1). But I want find it in header or programmatically.

In iOS I can't find version number in FacebookSDK.framework headers.

Comment: Any idea how you could print the installed Facebook app's version?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

After about 2014, simply do this:

```
NSLog( @"### running FB sdk version: %@", [FBSDKSettings sdkVersion] );
```

---

For very old versions. Before about 3.6:

I found an undocumented way to print the SDK version (FB_IOS_SDK_VERSION_STRING), try this

```
NSLog(@"### FB SDK VERSION : %@",
    [[FBRequestConnection class] performSelector:@selector(userAgent)]);
```

Worked for me with sdk 3.5.1

---

Update: As of FB SDK 3.6,  **"The SDK version number is defined in FacebookSDK.h and available from [FBSDKSettings sdkVersion]"**

https://developers.facebook.com/ios/change-log-3.x/

Comment: thanks,
But there's another remark,
The facebook download page currently says Facebook 3.5
when you download it tells you 3.14
What's the difference ?

Comment: So you have to be running the code in a debug session to figure out the SDK? There's no way to tell which version of the SDK you have installed on your computer, by say, just looking in ~/Documents/FacebookSDK (the default install location). I want to look back in TimeMachine and see what I had installed in that location on my last release... @poloDelaVegas Is it possible to figure out the SDK version by just looking at the library files installed on my computer?

Comment: Looks like you need to also include #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

Answer (score 21):

You can find the version of your Facebook SDK in `FBSDKCoreKit.h` defined as

`#define FBSDK_VERSION_STRING @"X.XX.X"`. Have a look at the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at `FBSDKVersion.h`. There's a define there:

`#define FB_IOS_SDK_VERSION_STRING @"3.2.1"`

Comment: I don't even have that file.

Comment: Right, that probably only works if the source is added too. For our project, it's added as a compiled framework.

Comment: I don't have the source.  How can I get it programmatically?  Is there a call?

Answer (score 9):

For those running SDK version >= 4, `[FBSDKSettings sdkVersion]`.

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSLog(@"### Running FB SDK Version: %@", [FBSDKSettings sdkVersion]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the SDK directory I did:

```
% find . -name \*.h -exec fgrep -i version {} /dev/null \;
```

Amongst other stuff, the following line was returned:

```
./FBSDKCoreKit.framework/Headers/FBSDKCoreKit.h:#define FBSDK_VERSION_STRING @"4.11.0"
```

This will help you identify the version without needing to actually link/run/log.

Facebook might possibly be the only technology company in the world that omits the version number from their tar/zip file, as well as the unpacked root directory. I find this baffling.

Answer (score 2):

In swift 2, FBSDK 4.4 you can output the version string:

```
print("FBSDK Version: \(FBSDK_VERSION_STRING)");
//outputs:
//FBSDK Version: 4.4.0
```

FBSDKSettings.version() returned 0 for me.

Answer (score 2):

To check the current version of facebook SDK use below line:

```
    print("SDK version \(FBSDKSettings .sdkVersion())")
```

In my case, SDK version 4.8.0

Tested against swift 2.0 and xCode 7.0+

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get it on SPM after 11.0 from Xcode 12.

Answer (score 1):

Import the facebook core kit

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
```

You can print the SDK version using the below

```
print(Settings.shared.sdkVersion)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook SDK 3.18, I had to do

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSLog( @"My app is running FB sdk version: %@", [FBSettings sdkVersion]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try(Android) - I only posted this because I was looking for this answer and didn't see for android.

```
String s = FacebookSdk.getSdkVersion();
                Log.d("FacebookSKD_V",s);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pods you can check in the Info.plist file:

`"Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/Support Files/Info.plist"`

The version is the key `CFBundleShortVersionString`

My version was 4.18.0

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
  <string>en</string>
  <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
  <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
  <string>${PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}</string>
  <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
  <string>6.0</string>
  <key>CFBundleName</key>
  <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
  <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
  <string>FMWK</string>
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
  <string>4.18.0</string>
  <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
  <string>????</string>
  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
  <string>${CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION}</string>
  <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
  <string></string>
</dict>
</plist>
```