# How do I know which Facebook iOS SDK I have installed

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I've developed an iOS App with Facebook iOS SDK.
It was a while back and I don't know which SDK version I used.
How can I check it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736831/find-facebook-sdk-version

Answer (score 2):

In the end of `FacebookSDK.h` there is a macro:

> `#define FB_IOS_SDK_VERSION_STRING @"3.10.0"`