# Which version the Facebook iOS SDK that Facebook Unity SDK v6.2.2 is rely on?

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, sdk

The change-log of Facebook Unity SDK don't write about the Facebook iOS SDK version for Facebook Unity SDK v6.2.2.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/change-log

And also here, preparing for iOS9 page.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

We just want to know which version of Facebook iOS SDK that Facebook Unity SDK v6.2.2 is rely on.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best approach but this should work. In your app delegate or anywhere convenient:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
```

and then in one of the methods:

```
NSLog(@"Fb iOS SDK version: %@", [FBSDKSettings sdkVersion]);
```

That should give you the version number of the Facebook SDK. I tried this with `Unity 7.1.0` and it gave back `Fb iOS SDK version: 4.6.0`

But if the SDK is using an older version of the Facebook SDK, the import should fail and if that happens, you can try the steps outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17571491/405525).